# Trying to make a marble texture

Tags: roughness

Does anyone know how to finesse the lighting in blender so these annoying white light reflection squares disappear?

[image]

Comment: you can use icosphere or a quad sphere instead https://medium.com/@oscarsc/four-ways-to-create-a-mesh-for-a-sphere-d7956b825db4